# Slow SignalR HubConnection Start

Tags: c#, localhost, client, signalr, self-hosting

My Question: Is there a way to speed up the initial connect to the hub?

**Details:**

I am using SignalR at a selfhosted Webservice @Win 8.1.
The Hub application got local clients and remote clients.

I granded SignalR access via DNS, localhost and 127.0.0.1 by:

```
'netsh http add urlacl url=http://<Replace>:<Port>/ user=Everyone'
```

Usually all clients even the local ones are using DNS. And it works.

My problem is one sporned child process (using c# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection). It usually connects withing 400ms. Thats ok. But sometimes it takes seconds.

I have tried to switch at this client to 127.0.0.1 and localhost but without any change.

Afterwards the initial connect, SignalR is pritty fast.

If there is no easy way I have to switch back to plain UDP.

SignalR Config at Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRStartUp))]
namespace Onsite
{
    public class SignalRStartUp
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder pApp)
        {
            try
            {
                pApp.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                pApp.MapSignalR();
                pApp.UseFileServer(true);

                var lOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    ContentTypeProvider = new CustomContentTypeProvider(),
                    FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(Constants.Root)
                };

                pApp.UseStaticFiles(lOptions);

                // Configure Web API for self-host. 
                var lConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
                lConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute("RemoteApi", "api/{controller}/{action}");
                lConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
                pApp.UseWebApi(lConfig); 
            }
            catch (Exception lEx)
            {
                Logger.Error(lEx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Startup at the Client:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string pHost = null)
{
    var lHost = pHost ?? GetMainClientDns();
    return string.Format("http://{0}{1}", lHost, SignalRPort);
}

private void StartSignalR()
{
    try
    {
        var lConnectionString = GetConnectionString("127.0.0.1");

        var lStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        lStopWatch.Restart();
        IsConnectingHost = true;

        _connection = new HubConnection(lConnectionString, string.Format("AccessKey={0}&Role={0}", Constants.AccessKeyPlugIn));
        _connection.Reconnected += SetConnected;
        _connection.Reconnecting += SetDisConnected;

        MTalkHub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("OnsiteHub");

        MTalkHub.On("RequestSetNext", RequestSetNext);
        MTalkHub.On("RequestSetPrevious", RequestSetPrevious);
        MTalkHub.On("RequestEcho", RequestEcho);

        _connection.TransportConnectTimeout = _transportConnectTimeout;

        var lTask = _connection.Start();
        lTask.Wait();

        lStopWatch.Stop();

        SetConnected();
     }
    catch (TargetInvocationException lEx)
    {
        IsDisconnected = true;
        Task.Run(() => TryToConnect());
        Logger.Fatal(string.Format("Server failed to start. Already running on: '{0}'", lConnectionString), lEx);
    }
    catch (Exception lEx)
    {
        IsDisconnected = true;
        Task.Run(() => TryToConnect());
        Logger.Fatal(string.Format("Connecting to: '{0}' failed!", lConnectionString.ToStringNs()));
    }
    finally
    {
        IsConnectingHost = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this just be a case of your IIS application pool recycling on a default timer? That would cause your entire application to essentially restart and everything needs to be reinitialised which would add a few seconds delay to any call, even local ones. Usually it's best to change the default settings for recycling so that it recycles only at a specific time or set of times since the default is something like every 10-20 minutes.

Comment: good point! I have stumble of this problem some years ago on our IIS webservices. But as far as i know, selfhosted webservices with cors do not need any IIS or even IIS Express. It is just a single process without recycling. I just searched after some type of idle or sleep mode at the StartUp of the IAppBuilder and google bit didn't find somthing useful. My someone know more on this topic? I will add my Startup Method to my questen details.

Comment: Can it be fallback? By default SiganlR is using an auto transport which will try connecting using websockets and if this fails it will try serverSentEvents and finally it will try longPolling. The timeout to try the next transport is (AFAIR) 5 secs. Also, not that SignalR makes 3 HTTP requests when starting a connection so if for whatever reason server responds slowly the client can't start quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bugfix for another issue I the long initial connect was also gone.

What I have found: There was a race condition and rarely a lock with FileAccess via network share blocked the Hub by updating the local cached thumbnails.

Thx anyway!